# Google Tag Manager not picking up CSS Selector

Tags: tags, click, google-tag-manager

I'm currently trying to get Google Tag Manager to fire a click tag on my homepage for particular elements on the page. Not all elements are links so I'm using: Click - All Elements >> Some Clicks as my trigger type and added a condition of a specific CSS Selector for the tag to fire.

GTM is saying it does not see the value matching in the CSS however when I look at the Tag Details, I can see that there should be a match:
[Tag Details page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzCz9.png). I've also tried matching RegEx matching the click element and tried form element as well. The value is present in both of these when looking at "variables" in the GTM preview.

I'm looking to capture the click text within each of the sections of the homepage to determine which section is getting the most attention without getting the clutter of accidental clicks on nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really share the site you're working on. That may be interpreted as link spam, especially from new accounts.

Try using this:

```
Click - All Elements -> 
Some Clicks -> 
Click Element -> 
Matching CSS selector ->
```

And then this selector: `#featured-services, #featured-services *`

If this doesn't completely fix your issue, add a screenshot of your trigger as well as the block of HTML **as text** for us to be able to narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, still learning. This worked for the section I was looking for. If I wanted to add multiple elements to grab other sections such as #element-number-2 and #element-number-3, would I have to combine them all using regex while matching a CSS selector?

Comment: Although I am not a questioner, It works for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Michael, lost your question. But no, no regex is required to combine different selectors. Just separate them with a comma.